# Acronym Definitions

Tags: feature-request

Subject area SE sites should have an acronym wiki specific to the jargon/subject matter for each site.  Then, acronyms in posts (questions, answers, comments, tag wikis, etc.) could be automatically linked to their respective page in the acronym wiki.  The acronym wiki page could also be tagged. :)  Points awarded for contributing to the acronym wiki could be scored similarly to how tag wiki contributions are presently scored.

Answer (score 10):

Communities can do this now (and it's been suggested on occasion) by creating a **"Glossary of Terms" in meta** and linking any post containing those terms to it.

But there are two big implementation gotchas that turn up in actual practice:

1. These often start off strong but, more often than not, fall into disrepair as people fail to keep it up.
2. It is often *overused* where every post starts getting *pock-marked* with entirely too-basic entries and the Glossary becomes more bloated than useful.

It's a decent idea in an *ideal* sense. But sometimes when we come up with a solution to solve an instance of a problem we see, the broader implementation of how it turns out in actual practice is something much less, um… useful.

Comment: Some even do it on the main site rather than in Meta... like Cooking.SE's [list of terms](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/784/translating-cooking-terms-between-us-uk-au-ca-nz) in different versions of English (eg. biscuit-UK vs biscuit-US). Obviously, this is a slightly different example but it serves a similar purpose.

Answer (score 4):

It's an interesting idea. But I'd say unnecessary for several reasons.

1. Stack Exchange sites are, by definition, for '[Expert communities](https://stackexchange.com/)', so it could be said that people should already know the acronyms. They're not educational sites, they're professional resources.
2. The questions posed are expected to be of a high quality - which would mean introducing the acronyms when writing the text: *"I am working with TWT (This Widget Thing) and am having issues with..."*. This also means people don't have to browse off to a different page to understand some of the terminology used in a question.
3. It's hard to keep up to date. Just look at how many tags there are with minimal / inaccurate descriptions. And these are actually useful things for helping navigate the site. Unclear acronyms are not really blockers to people finding content on the site.

So I think the effort involved in creating and maintaining such a resource is probably outweighed but the lack of necessity and benefit of it.

Comment: I disagree that SE sites are strictly expert communities.  A number of sites specifically bill themselves as "personal" this or that, and Stack Overflow, for example, makes room for students to ask homework questions.  Are you impmlying that we should be flagging questions that use obscure acronyms?

Comment: @JimFell No, they're not to be flagged, as content is not a moderator issue. But I'd suggest questions using acronyms should be edited to include the full name of the term. Moderators don't need to do that, it's what the community are good at already.